# 445 CRITICAL 403 {"message": "Resource not accessible by integration", } gernerate a error in action

Tags: java, action

445 CRITICAL 403 {"message": "Resource not accessible by integration", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flMG0.png)

I want to be able to get useful solutions,Now seems to be a resource problems